# android "Illegal Access" cordovaGeolocation

Tags: ionic, geolocalización, ng-cordova

he instalado el plugin de corodova geolocation, podrian decirme ¿porque debido ese error?, lo intale como esta en esta pagina http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/.

y solo puse:

```
$cordovaGeolocation
 .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
 .then(function (position) {
   var lat  = position.coords.latitude
   var long = position.coords.longitude
 }, function(err) {
   // error
 });
```

en el Androidmanifest.xml tiene esta configuración:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

y en config.xml

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

controlador:

```
 function controlfproductoG ($scope, $timeout, $http, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, productosDato, urlRoot, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $interpolate, $stateParams, $animate, historialPagina, $cordovaGeolocation){
    existeLocalStorage();
    var typeT, cardTypes, beneficiosT, beneficioLocal, countProductoId,    productoSelecionado, productoSelecionadoB;
    var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    var countDato = 0;
    var countSwith = 0;
    var countSwithB = 1;
    var countCards = 0;

    var cateId = ($stateParams.categoria == '') ? 0 : $stateParams.categoria;

    $scope.cards = [];

    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {
         var lat = position.coords.latitude;
         var long = position.coords.longitude;
         console.log(lat + ', ' + long);
      }, function (error) {
         console.log(error)
      })
 }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Verifica si en el android manifest estan los `<uses-permission`

Comment: @sioesi, si si los tiene, editare la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes instalado el plugin?

Comment: Si es que tienes todo como corresponde, intenta desinstalarlo e instalarlo nuevamente.

Comment: @sioesi, si los desinstale y lo volvi a instalar, sera limpiar el proyecto?

Answer (score 1):

Instala el plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

esto puede ser causa de "Illegal Access"

Comment: ya lo instalé con todo y agregado el cordova.js en el proyecto, desistalado y volvi a isntalaralo y no funciona